# Plot a Vertical Line after a certain number of days as specified

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I want to be able to plot a vertical line on a daily chart after a certain days and bars have passed. The code below plots only the first vertical line :(

```
//@version=5
indicator("V", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)
tempTime = timestamp(2022,01,31,02,20)
plotTime = input.time(defval=timestamp("31 Jan 2022 00:00 +0000"), title="Time")
plot((time == plotTime) ? 10e20 : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 1, title = "MyLine", style = plot.style_histogram)

plotTime2 = plotTime + 5
plot((plotTime == plotTime2) ? 10e20 : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 1, title = "MyLine", style = plot.style_histogram)

plotTime3 = plotTime + 9 
plot((plotTime2 == plotTime3) ? 10e20 : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 10, title = "MyLine", style = plot.style_histogram)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example we figure out how much time is in one bar by subtracting the close time from the open time of a bar. We can then use that with your number of bars forward as a multiplier. We also need to check time against the new plot times rather than the plot times against one another, which will never align

```
//@version=5
indicator("V", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)
tempTime = timestamp(2022,01,31,02,20)
plotTime = input.time(defval=timestamp("31 Jan 2022 00:00 +0000"), title="Time")
plot((time == plotTime) ? 10e20 : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 1, title = "MyLine", style = plot.style_histogram)

var barTime = time_close - time
plotTime2 = plotTime + (5 * barTime)
plot((time == plotTime2) ? 10e20 : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 1, title = "MyLine", style = plot.style_histogram)

plotTime3 = plotTime + (9 * barTime) 
plot((time == plotTime3) ? 10e20 : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 10, title = "MyLine", style = plot.style_histogram)
```

Cheers and best of luck with your coding and trading

Comment: Thank You.... I tried on "NIFTY" and it plots the line only on 31st Mar 2022 but not 5 days and bars later